# How to calculate Pairwise Fst using hierfstat?

Tags: r, statistics, dna-sequence, genetics

I am having a lot of trouble calculating correct Fst values for my SNPs. Whilst my data doesn't have any population in it, I have added pop as a factor, separating my data into 4 different populations. One from a River, one from a lake and the two others are outgroups (different species).

I am using a STRUCTURE file for my loci, with the missing values -9... I tried to code this as NA instead as I thought this would cause problems but the missing has to be an integer.

```
MG_Sample10                         3   2   3   2   3   0   2   2   0   0   3   3   0   1   1   2   0   2   0   3   1   0   3   1   3   2   1   3   3   1   0   2   3   0   2   -9  -9  3
MG_Sample13                         3   2   3   2   3   0   -9  1   0   0   3   2   2   1   1   1   0   2   0   3   -9  -9  3   0   3   2   1   3   3   3   2   2   2   3   2   -9  -9  3   0   2   2   3   1   1   0   0   3   2   2   1   3   0   1   1
```

My populations are coded 1-4 in a single column corresponding to the samples. I have used the code below.

```
library(adegenet)

library(hierfstat)

library(reshape)

file <- read.structure("file.str")

population <-read.csv("population.csv", header= F)

file@pop <- as.factor (population$V1)

hierfile <- genind2hierfstat(file)

FST <- pairwise.fst(file, pop=NULL, res.type=c("dist", "matrix"))
```

My Fst values keep coming out really low, the highest being 0.15 between my River population and my lake population. The out groups have minus values. I was hoping to maybe get something like 0.2 for the two populations I am comparing and maybe 0.6 for the out groups since they should not be interbreeding!

Comment: This sounds like more of a Statistical question, rather than a programming one, in which case it might be a better fit for [stats.se]. Either way, you need to include more information about your data and problem. Are you sure that these Fst values are actually incorrect? They could also be a side effect of some weirdness with how your data is represented in the structure, but without being able to see the data, we can't help with that.

Comment: Hi I've added an example of what my data looks like, its 50 individuals long and has about 29400 columns for each loci. I'll post on Cross Validated- thanks!